# Microprofile | Config - Testing with dynamic values

Tags: java, jboss-arquillian, apache-tomee, microprofile, tomee-8

I am using Microprofile Config (`@Inject`, not `ConfigProvider`) in my application. I have a configuration that takes different branches for different values. In order to test (`Arquillian`) all paths in my code, I need to be able to change this value at runtime. Can someone offer tips on how to achieve this? My properties are set using system properties, but I'm open to ideas on how to handle this.

Answer (score 3):

You could register a `ConfigSource` which can be configured easily. 
You can look at the one I wrote one for the mp-config TCK itself:
https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-config/blob/master/tck/src/main/java/org/eclipse/microprofile/config/tck/configsources/ConfigurableConfigSource.java

For adding this ConfigSource to your Arquillian @Deployment check this test:
https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-config/blob/1499b7bf734eb1710fe3b7fbdbbcb1ca0983e4cd/tck/src/main/java/org/eclipse/microprofile/config/tck/ConfigAccessorTest.java#L52

The important lines are:

```
.addClass(ConfigurableConfigSource.class)
.addAsServiceProvider(ConfigSource.class, ConfigurableConfigSource.class)
```

And then tweak the values

```
ConfigurableConfigSource.configure(config, "my.config.entry", "some new value");
```

Comment: My only concern for this implementation, is if it will work for simple bean values, such as [the following](https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-config/blob/1499b7bf734eb1710fe3b7fbdbbcb1ca0983e4cd/tck/src/main/java/org/eclipse/microprofile/config/tck/SimpleValuesBean.java#L37-L39). Can you address this concern? Also, `onAttributeChange` does not seem to be in a release version yet, so I will eagerly wait for it to come.

Comment: You don't need `onAttributeChange` for the task you want. It's just in there because the current TCK already implements the newer mp-config API. Just leave this part out. Regarding the @Dependent SimpleValuesBean: of course if you inject a java native type into a class then it will not pick up any changes in the underlying config due to being final. Use a Provider<Integer> for it for example.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to the [Microprofile Config: Spec: Configsource](https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-config/blob/master/spec/src/main/asciidoc/configsources.asciidoc) which mentions as the following: -

> System properties (default ordinal=400).
>
> Environment variables (default ordinal=300).
>
> A ConfigSource for each property file
>   META-INF/microprofile-config.properties found on the classpath.
>   (default ordinal = 100).

This means the `system properties` is a highest priority here. Then we may set the default value at the `META-INF/microprofile-config.properties` and override it if needed by the `system properties` instead.

During the integration test we are able to set the `system properties` together with use the `javax.inject.Provider` to make it retrieving dynamically so that the default value is overridden as the following example :-

```bash
# META-INF/microprofile-config.properties
my.key=original
```

```java
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Provider;

import org.eclipse.microprofile.config.inject.ConfigProperty;

public class SomeClass {
    @Inject
    @ConfigProperty(
        name = "my.key"
    )
    private Provider<String> key1;

    public String doSomethingWithConfig() {
        return key1.get();
    }
}
```

```java
import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;
import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.InSequence;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Assert;

@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class SomeClassTester {

    @Inject
    private SomeClass someclass;

    @Test
    @InSequence(1)
    public void whenTestDefaultConfig() {
        Assert.assertEquals("The value must be a defualt.",
                            "original", 
                            this.someclass.doSomethingWithConfig());
    }

    @Test
    @InSequence(2)
    public void whenTestOverrideMPConfig() {

        System.setProperty("my.key",
                           "new-value");
        Assert.assertEquals("The value must be overridden",
                            "new-value", 
                            this.someclass.doSomethingWithConfig());
    }

}
```

#### EDIT1

Furthermore if we would like to take control over the `system properites`, the [System Rules](https://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/) will make our live easier. They provide [ClearSystemProperties](https://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/#ClearSystemProperties), [ProvideSystemProperty](https://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/#ProvideSystemProperty) and [RestoreSystemProperties](https://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/#RestoreSystemProperties) as the following example from their document.

```java
public class MyTest {
    @Rule
    public final RestoreSystemProperties restoreSystemProperties
     = new RestoreSystemProperties();

    @Test
    public void overrideProperty() {
        //after the test the original value of "MyProperty" will be restored.
        System.setProperty("MyProperty", "other value");
        ...
    }
```

}

Comment: `System.setProperty` will surely work. But be careful when running tests in parallel. You might use an own custom ConfigurableConfigSource with stores the config in a @RequestScoped bean to isolate between different threads.